# Rolling dice question

Tags: probability, dice

I know that when 4 dice are rolled the probability of all 4 dice being 6's is .0008.
How can I find the probability when all 3 dice are 6's when 3 dice are rolled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a $1/6$ chance that rolling the first dice gives $6$. There is likewise a $1/6$ chance for the second and third dice. Since these are independent events, we can simply multiply to find that the probability is

$$\frac 1 6 \cdot \frac 1 6 \cdot \frac 1 6 = \frac 1 {216}$$

Comment: This of course assumes that all dice are all fair.  Could the probability (.0008) of rolling four 6s be relevant to the problem?  (.0008 is only a round-off of $6^{-4}$.)  Having said that (becasue I DO beieve that your answer is correct) one would have to at least assume that if a die isn't fair then all dice are unfair with the same probability of rolling a 6.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the $4$ dices are identical in nature. Let $p$ be the probability that the first throw of any of the $4$ dices yields a $6$. Then by the given condition $p^4 = 0.0008$. So the required probability is $p^3 = (0.0008)^{\frac {3} {4}} = 0.0048.$ (approx.)